# How to solve the particular solution of the differential equation(from wave equation) by Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations

how to solve the particular solution of the under differential equation by mathematica？$$\nabla^{2} \vec{E}-\varepsilon_{0} \mu_{0} \varepsilon_{r} \mu_{r} \frac{\partial^{2} \bar{E}}{\partial t^{2}}=0$$ and $$\nabla^{2}=\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z^{2}}$$
The particular solution is such like $\vec{E}=\vec{E}_{0} \cos (\omega t-\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r})$

> It's from the wave equation.(°ー°〃)

Comment: …Are you only interested in the particular solution with the form $\vec{E}=\vec{E}_{0} \cos (\omega t-\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r})$? Or you think the phrase "particular solution" only refers to something looks like $\vec{E}=\vec{E}_{0} \cos (\omega t-\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r})$? If the latter, your understanding for "particular solution" is wrong, and I'd suggest spend some time learning the basics of PDE first.

Comment: You could start with this `sol = DSolveValue[ D[u[x, t], t, t] - c^2  D[u[x, t], x, x] == 0, 
   u[x, t], {x, t}];
sol /. C[2][_] -> 0 /. C[1][x_] -> Cos[x] // PowerExpand`

Comment: Or do this  `D[u[x, t], t, t] - c^2  D[u[x, t], x, x] == 0 /. u -> 
   Function[{x, t}, Cos[ \[Omega] t -  k x]] // FullSimplify`

Comment: There is not much to calculate as you already have an eigenfunction of your equation: the laplacian term gives  - k^2 E and the time derivative: -w^2 E. Therefore your equation simplifies to: -k^2 E + epsilon mu w^2 E ==0 -->  k^2 == epsilon mu w^2